# Gecko driver exe proxy with python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, exe, gecko

If I use selenium with IE and Chrome web driver, does Gecko driver run?

I have read, that Gecko driver exe uses proxy. How is that affect to my project? Does internet traffic flow through a proxy server?
If the python code is converted to an exe on 1st pc and this exe runs on another pc (2nd pc, where python is not installed) then how is that affect to the internet traffic, will be forwarding or something like that?
The code i use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Gecko is for FireFox so it shouldn't run when using IE/Chrome.

Comment: Chrome uses proxy or something like that? I totally dont understand what does here proxy meaning when i read the documents

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-Jq9GrNVVc

Comment: proxy mean bridge or driver not proxy IP

Comment: how this affect the code. I mean i will convert py to exe and run on another pc